# Saving a new value to the db using the whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I'm trying to save a value in my db every hour.  Let's say it saves a random string of characters to the letter field in my randomizer table.  I have the whenever gem installed and my schedule.rb runs every hour calling a class method in my model.  It doesn't seem to save a value the way I have it set up.

Here is my schedule.rb:

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
set :environment, 'development'

every 1.hour do
  runner "Randomizer.rand_letters"
  command "echo 'random job attempted.'"
end
```

Here is my Randomizer model:

```
class Randomizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.rand_letters
    @random_string = Randomizer.new(letters: 'asdfg')
    @random_string.save   
  end
end
```

Here is my output when I run whenever:

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/action/workspace/word-vomit && bin/rails runner -e             development '\''Randomizer.rand_letters'\'' >> /home/action/workspace/word-        vomit/log/cron.log 2>&1'                                                     

0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'echo '\''random job attempted.'\'' >>     /home/action/workspace/word-vomit/log/cron.log 2>&1'                                                                                                                          

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file     was not updated.                                                                                                                                          
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

Comment: Use `save!` instead of `save` and see what happens.

Comment: is this is all the code of Randomizer class, it does not have any validations?